# \citet vs \cite using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, cite-package

This one looks like a question that should be solved just reading the package manual, but oddly I couldn't solve it neither that way.

I'm using `natbib` for an author-date bibliography style. I understood the difference between `\citet` and `\citep`. But, I can't understand the difference between `\citet` and the plain `\cite`.

Are they equal? Should I change all the `\cite` in `\citet`? (When I started writing I was using the classical 'Vancouver' style without `natbib`). Apparently the outputs of `\cite` and `\citet` look exactly the same.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The behavior of `\cite{<key>}` with `natbib` depends on the citation format (numerical vs. author-year) of the bibliography style in use. Thus, the results can be inconsistent (if you switch styles) and it's best to convert to `\citet` and `\citep` as appropriate.

From [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) (v8.31b) documentation, page 6:

> Both `\citep` and `\citet` are defined by `natbib` and are thus not
>   standard. The standard LaTeX command `\cite` should be avoided,
>   because it behaves like `\citet` for author-year citations, but like
>   `\citep` for numerical ones. There are many other commands for other
>   special effects (Section 2.4).

Comment: I missed that part in the natbib documentation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of writing guidelines I would write:

- `Statement A is true \citep{jon90}.` is printed as
  "Statement A is true (Jones et al., 1990)" or
- `Statement A is true as shown by \citet{jon90}.` is printed as
  "Statement A is true as shown by Jones et al. (1990)" or
- `Statement A is true according to \citet{jon90}.` is printed as
  "Statement A is true according to Jones et al. (1990)" or
- `\citet{jon90} showed that statement A is true.` is printed as
  "Jones et al. (1990) showed that statement A is true.".

In these 4 examples it would be grammatically wrong to replace `\citet` by `\citep` or vice versa. Depending on the natbib style the citations are printed slightly differently, but as far as I know they are always printed such that `\citet` and `\citep` stay grammatically correct independent of the natbib style.

`\cite` however would be either grammatically wrong for the first of the 4 examples or for the last 3 of the 4 examples depending on the natbib style. (For some natbib style `\cite` is equivalent to `\citet` and for some `\cite` is equivalent to `\citep`.)

For more examples see https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-2/garcia/garcia.pdf

For further variations and optional arguments see
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_citation_styles or
https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/5g9kn1/whats_the_difference_between_cite_citep_and_citep/, e.g.,
`Statement A is true as shown in \citet[Theorem~1]{jon90}.` is printed as
"Statement A is true as shown in Jones et al. (1990, Theorem 1)" or