# Citation call-out with publication year placed in squared brackets when using apacite

Tags: natbib, apacite

The RAE is the institution that ensures the stability of the Spanish language. They have a [norm](https://www.rae.es/dpd/par%C3%A9ntesis) that states that when making citations inside parenthesis, the publication year of the cited item must be in square brackets, like in:

> This citation (according to Knuth[1986])

How can I create a citation command that employs brackets instead of parentheses? I must use the `apacite` citation management package.

Here my MWE, that does not work as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = 1986,
    title = {The {\TeX{ book},
  }}}
\end{filecontents}

% \cite using square brackets:
\newcommand{\citesb}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\BBOP}{[}%
    \renewcommand{\BBCP}{]}%
    \cite{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Demonstration}
This citation (according to \cite{Knu86}).
% It should print:
% This citation (according to Knuth(1986)).

This citation (according to \citesb{Knu86}).
% It should print:
% This citation (according to Knuth[1986]).

This citation (according to \cite{Knu86}).
% It should print:
% This citation (according to Knuth(1986)).

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
% It should print
% Knuth, D. E. (1986). The TEX book, .
\end{document}
```

Here a picture of the current behaviour of my MWE:

[image]

Comment: Is omitting the parentheses/brackets around the year field an option?

Comment: No, the Spanish style does not allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it a bit odd that you had to use `\!\!` in [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691339/35864) to cancel some unwanted space. Indeed there is an unprotected space in the definition of `\setcitestyle`.

Instead of fixing the lengthy definition of `\setcitestyle` I'd like to offer the following solution that changes the brackets only locally (so that there is no need to "switch back" to round brackets).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mkciteusesquarebrackets}{%
  \renewcommand\NAT@open{[}%
  \renewcommand\NAT@close{]}}

\newcommand{\citepb}[2][]{{\mkciteusesquarebrackets\citep[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\citetb}[2][]{{\mkciteusesquarebrackets\citet[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year   = 1986,
  title  = {The {\TeX}book},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Demonstration}
This citation (according to \citep{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citepb{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citet{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citetb{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citep[section 10]{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citepb[section 10]{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citet[section 10]{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citetb[section 10]{Knu86}).

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: This citation (according to (Knuth, 1986)). This citation (according to [Knuth, 1986]). This citation (according to Knuth (1986)). This citation (according to Knuth [1986]). This citation (according to (Knuth, 1986, section 10)). This citation (according to [Knuth, 1986, section 10]). This citation (according to Knuth (1986, section 10)). This citation (according to Knuth [1986, section 10]).]

Note that I did not define a `\citeb` since `natbib` recommends to use only `\citet` and `\citep` and avoid `\cite`. See for example [\citet vs \cite using natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186778/35864) and [cite and citep do the same thing for the acmart package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656195/35864).

---

Just for fun, here is a solution for `biblatex` that uses that `biblatex` automatically tracks parentheses if you use its own commands instead of literal `(` and `)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Demonstration}
This citation \mkbibparens{according to \parencite{sigfridsson}}.

This citation \mkbibparens{according to \parencite{sigfridsson}}.

This citation \mkbibparens{according to \textcite{sigfridsson}}.

This citation \mkbibparens{according to \textcite{sigfridsson}}.

This citation \mkbibparens{according to \parencite[section 10]{sigfridsson}}.

This citation \mkbibparens{according to \parencite[section 10]{sigfridsson}}.

This citation \mkbibparens{according to \textcite[section 10]{sigfridsson}}.

This citation \mkbibparens{according to \textcite[section 10]{sigfridsson}}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: This citation (according to [Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998]). This citation (according to [Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998]). This citation (according to Sigfridsson and Ryde [1998]). This citation (according to Sigfridsson and Ryde [1998]). This citation (according to [Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, section 10]). This citation (according to [Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, section 10]). This citation (according to Sigfridsson and Ryde [1998, section 10]). This citation (according to Sigfridsson and Ryde [1998, section 10]).]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Lovely solution!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own question with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = 1986,
    title = {The {\TeX{ book},
  }}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\citeb}[2][]{\!\!\setcitestyle{square}\citet[#1]{#2}\setcitestyle{round}\!\!}
\newcommand{\citepb}[2][]{\!\!\setcitestyle{square}\citep[#1]{#2}\setcitestyle{round}\!\!}
\newcommand{\citetb}[2][]{\!\!\setcitestyle{square}\citet[#1]{#2}\setcitestyle{round}\!\!}

\begin{document}
\section{Demonstration}
This citation (according to \citeb{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citep{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citepb{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citet{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citetb{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citeb[section 10]{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citep[section 10]{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citepb[section 10]{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citet[section 10]{Knu86}).

This citation (according to \citetb[section 10]{Knu86}).

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]